# remove gap in columns css grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
class UserControls {
  constructor() {
    this.sudokuTable = document.querySelector(".sudoku-table");
    this.createInput();
  }

  createInput() {
    let i;
    let input;
    for (i = 0; i < 9 * 9; i++) {
      input = document.createElement("INPUT");
      input.setAttribute("type", "text");
      input.setAttribute("value", 0);
      input.classList.add("input-style");
      this.sudokuTable.appendChild(input);
    }
  }
}


new UserControls()
```

```css
.sudoku-table {
  display: grid;
  background-color: green;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;

  margin-top: 25px;

  & > .input-style:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

.input-style {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sudoko Solver</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="description__title">Sudoku Solver</h1>
      <p class="description"><strong>Speed:</strong></p>
      <input
        id="speed"
        class="slider slider__reverse"
        type="range"
        min="10"
        max="100"
        value="50"
      />
      <button id="playBtn" class="btn">Play</button>
      <div class="sudoku-table"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a Sudoku style layout using javascript and input fields. At the moment I use javascript to insert all the input boxes i'll need. Then I tried to use CSS grid to create the 9x9 grid I'm looking for.

javascript:

```
class UserControls {
  constructor() {
    this.sudokuTable = document.querySelector(".sudoku-table");
    this.createInput();
  }

  createInput() {
    let i;
    let input;
    for (i = 0; i < 9 * 9; i++) {
      input = document.createElement("INPUT");
      input.setAttribute("type", "text");
      input.setAttribute("value", 0);
      input.classList.add("input-style");
      this.sudokuTable.appendChild(input);
    }
  }
}

export default UserControls;
```

CSS:

```
.sudoku-table {
  display: grid;
  background-color: green;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;

  margin-top: 25px;

  & > .input-style:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sudoko Solver</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="description__title">Sudoku Solver</h1>
      <p class="description"><strong>Speed:</strong></p>
      <input
        id="speed"
        class="slider slider__reverse"
        type="range"
        min="10"
        max="100"
        value="50"
      />
      <button id="playBtn" class="btn">Play</button>
      <div class="sudoku-table"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what my code creates:

[image]

I'd like to get rid of the green gaps.

How can that be done?

I tried setting `grid-column-gap: 0`
setting

```
margin: 0
```

Comment: Please turn this into a [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: That is not CSS - please modify the question to reflect that is SCSS or SASS.

Comment: I guess you didn't think the margin on every column `fr` would have any effect? Remove the `right-margin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick solution, you can set the height and width of `input-style` to 100%

```
.input-style {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Then set the same for your `sudoku-table` class:

```
.sudoku-table {
    //...
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Output:
[image]